# How can I make a two images sit on opposite ends using a LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have 2 images in a horizontal linear layout. I want one to sit on the left and another to sit on the very right. Like this

X----------------------------X

Here is my XML

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerBarLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/batteryImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/battery" android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/exit_button"
                style="@style/MotionMetrics.ExitButton"
                android:src="@drawable/exit_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Not sure why they aren't on opposite ends.

Photo:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a relative layout for this. Like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerBarLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/batteryImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/battery" android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exit_button"
            style="@style/MotionMetrics.ExitButton"
            android:src="@drawable/exit_button" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
         />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that. Almost there. Check out my screenshot I just added. The image doesn't exactly sit right.

Comment: Updated my response. Try that.

Comment: Same results as before, I also removed the style i had for it. Didn't make a difference aside from the height being level now

Comment: Works if i take out toRightOf:battery

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/batteryImageView" android:layout_gravity="right"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/exit_button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ImageView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the `android:layoutandroid:layout_gravity="left"` and the other to right. It works I tested it.